# XCode 4 - @private

Tags: xcode4, private, dealloc, init

I don't know if it's some setting I accidentally ticked, but tell me how to fix it please:

Whenever I create a new Obj-C class, it automatically looks like:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface MathUtilities : NSObject {
**@private**

}

@end
```

That line is automatically inserted. It never was there before, but something is not adding it. My files also now come with init and dealloc methods. Did something happen? Also, shouldn't it be importing Cocoa instead of Foundation?

This is XCode 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing to fix. XCode is creating stubs for you to fill out your code into. It's a time saver, thats all. It should be generating a header and implementation stub file for you, which you can extend like so:

Your header file (MathUtilities.h):

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface MathUtilities : NSObject {
@private:
    NSNumber * num;
}

- (void) doSomeWork;
@end
```

Your implementation file  (MathUtilities.m) :

```
#import "MathUtilities.h"

@implementation MathUtilities

- (id) init {
    self = [super init];
    if(self) {
        // Initialization code here.
    }

    return self;
}

- (void) dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void) doSomeWork {
    return;
}

@end
```

Comment: Would leaving it affect my program in anyway? And as for it suddenly appearing, why so? It never started appearing until now. All previous classes did not have this. And shouldn't it be importing Cocoa instead of Foundation? I know I did not say that in my question, but I just realized that too.

Comment: Well, you shouldn't be leaving it so much as using it. How do you normally generate your prototype and class implementation? Also, XCode 4 will import Foundation classes since they contain the bulk of basic classes that will be used in most programs. The Cocoa libraries contain lots of UI classes that aren't necessarily used as much.

Comment: Usually, my .h file would come without the @private. I create my Obj-C classes by using the Command+N and just selecting the Obj-C class, set the super to NSObject, and name it. It never added the private till now. And if XCode 4 imports Foundations, does it only import Cocoa when you first start a new project?

Comment: Oh yea, those are what my files look like. So is there any way to explain about why the @private just suddenly started appearing? Whenever I create my classes, I get both the files, but they were both usually void of the init, dealloc, and @private. Anything that I could have done so that now they are added?

Comment: @Jon, there have been some changes in XCode 4, as you have seen. The framework imports you see in your projects from now on will depend on what project type you start up (iOS or Mac, and application type). I encourage you to browse through the XCode 4 documentation to get a handle on all the changes in the IDE - http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html.

Comment: Oh yeah, forgot about that. Thanks!